# What does the 'Confidence' stat mean in Endless Legend?

Tags: endless-legend

What does the "Confidence" stat in Endless Legend mean/do? It has no mouseover explanation and it's not one of the primary stats.

[image: confidence 2 on a talisman]
(click to see full version)

Comment: There you go sir :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the bestiary](http://www.multimondes.net/Amplitude/EndlessLegend/Manuals/ThePeoplesOfAuriga.pdf):

> Confience (DEF bonus when receiving melee damages)
>
> Level 1 +20%
>   Level 2 +30%
>   Level 3 +40%